# How to choose EditText widget where I want to place a date from date picker?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-datepicker

I have one project where is two custom framelayout edittexts with buttons, which are open DatePickerFragmentDialog.
I need to choose between this two edittext widget where I want to place selected date from datepicker dialog.

It is a code where I create my `Fragment`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.butSince:
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            new ShowDate().setEditText(etSince);
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

            break;
    }
}
```

It is my `DatePickerFragment`:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

String date;
EditText editText;
ShowDate showDate;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    editText = new ShowDate().getEditText();
    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    date = day + "." + month + "." + year;
    editText.setText(date);


}
}
```

And its a "choose method" code:

```
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ShowDate {
EditText editText;

public EditText getEditText() {
    return editText;
}

public void setEditText(EditText editText) {
    this.editText = editText;
}
}
```

I have a `NullPointerException` in `onDateSet`.

Comment: what you want to set the date on two different edittext?

Comment: I would need to see the code of your **ShowDate** class to see how the **EditText**s are being initialized.